# VBA code for Nested for loop, to look certain value and copy paste entire column in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

**Current code** - I have written a code, in which it will search for a value present in Sheet2 B1 cell, in sheet 1 and copy paste that entire column in "Column C " and "column D".

**Required** - I want to loop the same thing, once B1 in sheet 2 is executed, check for value in B2 (sheet2), in Sheet1, if found, create a new sheet and paste entire column value in "Column C and D".
  Loop should run til all the rows in Sheet2 column B and for each value found create new sheet and paste.

please help me loop and edit this code.

Current code

```
  Sub Look_copy()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim K As Long, l As Long, i As Long, nRow As Long
    Dim valuee1 As Variant


Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    K = 3
    l = 4
    nRow = 1
    valuee1 = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value

    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        If sh1.Cells(nRow, i).Value = valuee1 Then
            sh1.Cells(nRow, i).EntireColumn.Copy sh2.Cells(1, K)
            sh1.Cells(nRow, i + 1).EntireColumn.Copy sh2.Cells(1, l)
            K = K + 1
            l = l + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i can understand that you find a value in the first row, copy the whole column to COl C and D of sheet1.  The below code does the same thing, but also loops for each cell in sheet 2 column B and adds new sheet before pasting. Try it!

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Range

    'loop unitl last row in sheet2 column b
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  

        'find value in sheet1
        Set x = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        'if value found
        If Not x Is Nothing Then

            'add new sheet
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheet1
            Set newSheet = ActiveSheet

            'copy entire column to column C nad D of new sheet
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(x.Column).Copy newSheet.Columns(3)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(x.Column).Copy newSheet.Columns(4)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Update:**

Below code to check values in column C in sheet3. For each value in Sheet2 Column C it will find the matching value in Sheet3 Row1, and copy values until the last row to Sheet2 Column B at the last available row.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Range

    'loop unitl last row in sheet2 column b
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'find value in sheet1
        Set x = Sheets("Sheet3").Rows("1:1").Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        'if value found
        If Not x Is Nothing Then

            With Sheets("Sheet3")
                .Range(x, .Cells(Rows.Count, x.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... its working perfect. Jus one more addition is required to this. there is one more column C in sheet 2, it has to find the value of that column in Row1 of sheet 3, if that is present, paste the entire contents in the same page as B1 value.     eg: Sheet 2 has column b1 and C1, check for b1 value in sheet1 and paste in new page, and check the c1 value in sheet3 and paste it page below the values of b1. how do i loop that? can you please help

Comment: I don't understand. do you still need help with the question? You seem to have an accepted answer from the other user?

Comment: Hi,.. code, mentioned above is working fine for the problem mentioned. where as i have to edit the code again to accommodate few other things.  eg: Sheet 2 has column b1 and C1, check for b1 value in sheet1 and paste in new page, and check the c1 value in sheet3 and paste it column below the values of b1.  how do i loop that?

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Look_copies()
    Dim rng1 As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) > 0 Then Look_copy cell, rng1, Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        Next
    End With
End Sub


Sub Look_copy(valCell As Range, rng1 As Range, pasteSht As Worksheet)
    Dim valuee1 As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    valuee1 = valCell.Value
    For Each cell In rng1
        If cell.Value = valuee1 Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Copy
            pasteSht.Cells(1, "C").Resize(, 2).PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```